# PHP set variable value again for sql query not working

Tags: php, mysql

Hello my question is quite simple, yet I can not understand why it works like this.

When I have set the varialbe $query once and then set it again it does not work.
Only when using an other name for the variable, for example $query2 it works.

WORKS :

```
$connect = mysql_connect("","","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("");
$query = "select post_title,id from wp_posts where post_status='publish'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
WHILE 1
$query2 = "SELECT meta_key FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE post_id='$id'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result2))
{
WHILE 2
}
}
```

NOT WORKS :

```
$connect = mysql_connect("","","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("");
$query = "select post_title,id from wp_posts where post_status='publish'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
WHILE 1
$query = "SELECT meta_key FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE post_id='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
WHILE 2
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$result` is a HANDLE representing the results of the query. Your second query is OVERWRITING the result of the first query, effectively killing the first query's results:

```
$result = mysql_query($query1);
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $result = mysql_query(...);
    ^^^^^^^---- overwrite occurs here
```

You run query #1, start the loop, run query #2. That query's results replaces the result from the first query, and gets completely consumed by the inner while() loop. When the inner loop finishes and control goes back up to the outer loop, there's no more data in this new `$result` handle, so the outer loop terminates as well.

Comment: Thanks again for adding the details.
In theory this would work because $query is no handle ?!

$query = "SELECT id FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE post_id='$id' and 
$result2 = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result2))

Comment: $query is just a string. once you've fed it to `mysql_query()`, you can throw the string away - the actual contents of the string, the query, are now copied into the mysql_*() innards.

Answer (score 3):

You are not only changing the `$query` variable, but also the `$result`. Which is in your `while`, screwing up the first result set. You just have to assign a new result set.

This will work:

```
$query = "select post_title,id from wp_posts where post_status='publish'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
   WHILE 1
   $query = "SELECT meta_key FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE post_id='$id'";
   $result2 = mysql_query($query);
   while($row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result2))
   {
      WHILE 2
   }
}
```

Comment: I did that, see my example. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are using while in while, it means yours second while:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result))
```

will overwrite yours first `$result`.

Comment: Thanks but Marc's explanation is a little bit more clear for me.